# Swift: UITableViewCell size to width of parent UITableView with autolayout enabled

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I'm experimenting with autolayout and am running into trouble with UITableViewCell since they're created at runtime. My cells are loaded from a xib from the main ViewController. This xib has View mode set to *Aspect Fill*.

I've read about different ways to do this online and have yet to get any of them working. What's considered the best way to handle this?

[image]

Comment: Can you not set the width of the cell in cellForRow AtIndexPath like this,      cell.frame.size.width = YourTableView.frame.size.width

Comment: This had no effect. I have height and width constraints on the image in the xib set to 66. I'll try removing that or making it relative to something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your constraints aren't set properly, as the cell is shorter than the image's height.

Using AutoLayout and self-sizing cells is the easiest way to handle what you want to do.  Once your constraints are setup properly for your custom cell, `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` can call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` and all the subview layout will be handled for you.

See the detailed walkthrough by [smileyborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/796419/smileyborg) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/4151918) to **Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights**.

He also provides workarounds for the minor [issue with the initial cell width being based on the storyboard cell](https://github.com/smileyborg/TableViewCellWithAutoLayoutiOS8/issues/10), instead of the tableView width. I worked around it by setting the cell's initial width to the tableView's width, as [Rasputin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3700509/rasputin) had suggested.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of self sizing cells.